# scope button of UISearchBar does not work on IOS 13 when using UISearchDisplayController

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, ios13

I have to maintain a quite old and large objective-c project.
Every thing works fine until `iOS12` but from `iOS13` the scope-button-bar of `UISearchBar` does not work with `UISearchDisplayController`.

I know that `UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated but I really don't want to migrate it to `UIDisplayController` because of some reasons.
I did some test and find out the problem might related to `UIDisplayController` as it block the user touch on the scope button.

**My code as below:**

```
@implementation MyUISearchDisplayController

- (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.active == visible){ return; }
    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [super setActive:visible animated:animated];
    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    if (visible)
    {
        [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
@end

@interface TopBarViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchDisplayController *searchController;

@end

@implementation TopBarViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //The default state for show-cancel-button and show-scope-bar of searchBar is false (not showing)
    self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"scope1", @"scope2", @"scope3", @"scope4"];
    self.searchController = [[MyUISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
}
```

The code above works as well until `IOS12`, but from `IOS13` I cannot touch the scope button. I guess the problem related to the `UIDisplayController` class.
So I'm thinking of overwrite some method of `UIDisplayController` but don't know how to start. Any body have experience with that. Any information would be appreciated. Thanks.

I'm quite new to `Objective-C` and `IOS`, I did a lot of search on google but no luck.

updated:
After some days debugging I solved my problem by overwriting the `hitTest` method of `UISearchBar` class.  The following should do the trick (also it's not a documented way)

```
@implementation MyUISearchBar

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UIView * touchedView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if(check version stuff){
        return touchedView;
    }
    UIView * scopeBar = [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"_scopeBar")];
    if(user touched the scopeBar){
        return scopeBar;
    }
    return touchedView;
}
```

Hope it helps some one.